# Close modal on esc press (pure JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my modal to close (have a class that sets it to `display: block` removed) on an esc press. Here's what I tried (which doesn't work and breaks the rest of my code):

```
if (modal.classList.contains('modal-visible')) {
  document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode === '27') {
      modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
    }
}
```

Here's the other code from my JS file for the modal:

```
const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
const closeIcon = document.querySelector('.close');

// When called, adds class that sets modal to display: block when player reaches water
function bringUpModal() {
  modal.classList.add('modal-visible');
}

// Closes modal (adding class that sets it back to display: none) upon user's clicking its close icon
closeIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
});

// Opens modal when player reaches water
Player.prototype.update = function(dt) {
    if (this.y === 25) {
        bringUpModal();
        this.y = 400;
    }
};
```

Doubt this is needed, but just in case, here's my CSS for the modal as well:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  width: 33%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f1f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #c5c4c4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Added by function bringUpModal() */
.modal-visible {
  display: block;
}

.modal-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Hi Natalie! You don't need the if check in your first code snippet. You want to set up a listener so that anytime the escape key is pressed, the `modal-visible` class is removed.
Also, if the if-check if false, the listener won't be created at all!
Finally, check that your parentheses and brackets match in your first code snippet. They look like they're not matched up, which may be why it appears to break your code :)

Comment: if (keyCode === 27) would be better, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an event listener for the modal when the page loads, not if the modal is visible. Also, use the `keydown` event instead of `keypress` as in some browsers the keypress event is only fired if the key outputs a character

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  width: 33%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f1f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #c5c4c4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Added by function bringUpModal() */
.modal-visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal" class="modal modal-visible" style="border: 2px solid black; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Key Code: "+keyCode+"<br/> Key: "+e.key+"<br/>";
    if (keyCode === 27) {//keycode is an Integer, not a String
      modal.classList.remove('modal-visible');
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Escape key pressed. Modal hidden.";
    }
});
</script>
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
 <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: keycode keyword is now depreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you only create the event listener if the modal is visible, it will simply never be created. Making the modal visible *afterward* will not re-execute your code. The if check has already occurred, already failed, and the event listener for keydown has already *not* been created. At no point will it be created.

```
var x = 2;
if (x === 1) {
  alert('yes');
}
x = 1;
```

In the above example, the alert never happens, even though `x` eventually becomes `1`. Similarly, your event listener never gets created.

At the same time, the keyCode is an integer, not a string. You will want to use `27` instead of `'27'`.