# Need to close the modal popup window when pressing the escape key

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a modal box popup functionality and I want to close this modal popup up box when someone hits the escape key. How to close the modal popup by pressing the escape key? Please see the 'run code snippet' by clicking on the full page view!
And also need to hide the previous key in the first image. Thnx.

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 58%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  margin-left: 300px;
  max-width: 779px;
  min-width: 779px;
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.close {
  position: relative;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
  left: 584px;
  top: 90px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -149px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  left: -10%;
}

.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -149px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  left: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calcutta Public School > Photogallery</title>
</head>

<body>

  <tr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <td>
          <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
        </td>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <td>
          <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x900" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
        </td>
      </div>
  </tr>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>

      <div class="mySlides">

        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
        <p id="caption" style="padding-bottom: 7px;font-size: 17px;">Annual function</p>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">

        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x900" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
        <p id="caption" style="padding-bottom: 7px;font-size: 17px;">Annual function</p>
      </div>
      <a class="prev" id="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on forming questions in a manner that best enables the community to provide assistance.  I moved your code into a snippet, but it has a missing closing tag; also, something is preventing the JS from executing properly.  I'd recommend getting a functional [mcve] in the question-- this will aid visitors to the page in understanding your question and enable them to offer guidance.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: This may be a possible duplicate which could answer your question: [Close modal on esc press (pure JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51293224/close-modal-on-esc-press-pure-js)

Comment: So where is the event listener for the keypress/keydown?

Answer (score 0):

try this hopefully this will fix the issue

In Javascript

---

```
document.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    if (e.key === "Escape") { 
        // hide modal code
        closeModal()
    }
});
```

In Jquery

---

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
 if (e.key === "Escape") { 
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  }
});
```